# jQuery how to replace src url

Tags: jquery, html, url, replace, load

I have a page that I screen scraped, the scraped page used a relative path for their images and when I load my page, the url of my site is being inserted on the src attr. I need to find some way of replacing my url with the url of the remote site in order for the images and other items that reference it to show up properly on my page.

The script I use to scrape is:

```
<script src="path_to_jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$document.ready(function() {
 $("#weather").load("http://weather.com" table:nth-child(3)", function() {
  $(this).find("img").each(function() {
   $(this).attr("src").replace('http://my_site.com', 'http://weather.com");
  });
 });
});
```

I have added the last line with .replace hoping to clean up the problem but so far it is not working. I need to keep the file path so when I replace my url with the target url the rest of the src attr needs to stay there. For example when the page is opened I see the table and all the text fine, but the images fail to load since the do not reside on my server. So I need to update the src attr from this:

```
http://my_site.com/images/sunny.jpg
```

to this:

```
http://weather.com/images/sunny.jpg
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you getting the HTML across domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `replace` call returns a new string containing the replacements.
Your code creates a new string that says `my_site.com` instead of `weather.com`, but doesn't do anything with the string.

You need to write the following:

```
$(this).attr("src", function(index, old) {
    return old.replace('http://my_site.com', 'http://weather.com");
});
```

Comment: I think it’s rather `function(index, old)`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be changing the url, the table still loads but it still doesn't update the path.

Comment: Then the domain part is probably different.  Add `alert(old)` and check what it says.

Comment: I just updated to 1.4 but still no love, also the alert doesn't pop anymore.

Comment: I am retarded! this works, I was staring at this thing for too long and didn't realize I put a https instead of http!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in  'http://weather.com"

```
$document.ready(function() {
 $("#weather").load("http://weather.com" table:nth-child(3)", function() {
  $(this).find("img").each(function() {
    var old_site= $(this).attr("src");
    var new_site= old_site.replace("http://my_site.com", "http://weather.com");
    $(this).attr("src",new_site);
  });
 });
});
```